# Timthumb.php script, how to hide the preview doing while it do it

Tags: timthumb

I really like to not have to make the thumbnails, so i use timthumb.php script. But on pageload the page is blank, and then all the thumbnail are poping here and there... it's fun, but make me crazy. So the question is, is it possible to hide the  where the thumbnail are done UNTIL it completed. so when the div is made visible, the thum are completed, not poping up !

Comment: Seem impossible... so how to detect that the page is finish rendering, and kind or ready.. is jquery (document.ready is just that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the answer : $(window).load(function() {} executed when every images are ready and not (windows).ready, that execute when the DOM is ready

reference ; http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/